# How to split an input from an Entry, in Tkinter, into individual characters?

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am working on making a ciphering program in Tkinter and need to seperate the words inputted into an Entry into seperate characters.

For example, if the user inputted the word "monkey",
it would be put into an array like this
seperatedWord = ["m","o","n","k","e","y"]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use `separatedWord = list(input_word)`.

Comment: wow, that was easy, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as commented by acw1668.

```
separatedWord = list(input_word)
```

you can [typecast](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-split-string-into-list-of-characters/) a string as list

try this code:

```
from tkinter import *


class MyEntry(Entry):
    def __init__(self, root, textvariable):
        Entry.__init__(self, master=root, textvariable=textvariable)

        #binding your trace handler to your textvariable
        textvariable.trace_add("write", self._traceHandler)

    #or just use this handler
    def _traceHandler(self, x, y, z):
        # code block
        print(self.getSeparatedWord())

    #you can call this
    def getSeparatedWord(self):
        value = self.get()
        return list(value)


root = Tk()
my_textvar = StringVar()
my_entry = MyEntry(root, my_textvar)
my_entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).